# Mesh Filter sharedMesh and mesh problem in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

Here is the method to generate cube collected over internet:

```
static void CreateCube () {
    Vector3[] vertices = {
        new Vector3 (0, 0, 0),
        new Vector3 (1, 0, 0),
        new Vector3 (1, 1, 0),
        new Vector3 (0, 1, 0),
        new Vector3 (0, 1, 1),
        new Vector3 (1, 1, 1),
        new Vector3 (1, 0, 1),
        new Vector3 (0, 0, 1),
    };

    int[] triangles = {
        0,
        2,
        1, //face front
        0,
        3,
        2,
        2,
        3,
        4, //face top
        2,
        4,
        5,
        1,
        2,
        5, //face right
        1,
        5,
        6,
        0,
        7,
        4, //face left
        0,
        4,
        3,
        5,
        4,
        7, //face back
        5,
        7,
        6,
        0,
        6,
        7, //face bottom
        0,
        1,
        6
    };

    GameObject tem = new GameObject ("Custom Mesh");
    tem.AddComponent<MeshFilter> ();

    Mesh mesh = tem.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh;
    mesh.Clear ();
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.Optimize ();
    mesh.RecalculateNormals ();
}
```

When I call this method, it gives me error :

> Instantiating mesh due to calling MeshFilter.mesh during edit mode. This will leak meshes. Please use MeshFilter.sharedMesh instead.
>   UnityEngine.MeshFilter:get_mesh()

And when finally I change `Mesh mesh = tem.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;` to `Mesh mesh = tem.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;`

It gives me another error, saying :

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I clicked on the *Console* and it referred me to the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need this to run in the Editor and not at run-time or in play mode.

You don't need to fetch the mesh from your MeshFilter, since you clear it anyway and replace all of its content. That mesh is also null, since you just created that component on the fly. It holds no references to anything.

Just do `Mesh mesh = new Mesh();` . Then assign it to the MeshFilter you just created on its sharedMesh field. The AddComponent<>() method returns the component, so no need to fetch it again.

Comment: `Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.Optimize();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();

        tem.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        tem.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();`